# Animation slowing down

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I have this code that after a while starts to slow down, I tried everything to reduce the script and increase performance but nothing works.
Here's a snippet with the code:

```js
var rotated = false;

function load() {
  setInterval(rain, 100);

  function rain() {
    var deg = rotated ? 0 : 20;
    var variable = screen.width + screen.width;
    var side = Math.floor((Math.random() * variable));
    var pos = -20;
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    var position = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 3;
    element.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    element.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    element.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    element.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    element.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    element.style.position = "absolute";
    element.style.width = "1px";
    element.style.height = "10px";
    element.style.top = "-20px";
    element.style.zIndex = position;
    document.getElementById('body').appendChild(element);
    if (position == 3) {
      element.style.backgroundColor = "#0018FF";
    }
    if (position == 1) {
      element.style.backgroundColor = "#8590FF";
    }
    element.style.left = side + 'px';
    setInterval(frame, 1);
    setInterval(frame2, 2);
    setInterval(frameChecker, 100);

    function frame() {
      pos++;
      element.style.top = pos + 'px';
    }

    function frame2() {
      side--;
      element.style.left = side + "px";
    }

    function frameChecker() {
      element.id = pos;
      if (element.id > screen.height + 500) {
        element.remove();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black
}

.center {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.center span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 500%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 45%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: white
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--CSS and SCRIPT here-->
  <title>GOT 404 ERROR</title>
</head>

<body onload="load()" id="body">
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%; position: relative;">
    <div class="center"><span>ERROR 404</span></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The whole JavaScript code is to make it rain, I think the problem is in somewhere in the variables but when I set as global only one dot of "rain" shows up (by global i mean outside of any function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i done it:

every 100 miliseconds is added a dot, this dot start 3 functions/dot to move and check its location, so i just added a "interval cleaner",(the `frameChecker()` `if` settement here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  body{
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
  html, body{
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: black}
  .center {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;}
  .center span{
 position: relative;
    font-size: 500%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 45%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: white}
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var rotated = false;
  function load(){
    setInterval(rain, 200);
   function rain(){
     var deg = rotated ? 0 : 20;
     var variable = screen.width+screen.width;
     var side = Math.floor((Math.random() * variable));
     var pos = -20;
     var element = document.createElement('div');
     var position = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 3;
     element.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
     element.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
     element.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
     element.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
     element.style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
     element.style.position = "absolute";
     element.style.width = "1px";
     element.style.height = "10px";
     element.style.top = "-20px";
     element.style.zIndex = position;
     document.getElementById('body').appendChild(element);
     if (position == 3){element.style.backgroundColor = "#0018FF";}
     if (position == 1){element.style.backgroundColor = "#8590FF";}
     element.style.left = side + 'px';
     var framee = setInterval(frame, 1);
     var framee2 = setInterval(frame2, 2);
     var frameCheckerr = setInterval(frameChecker, 100);
     function frame() {
      pos++;
      element.style.top = pos + 'px';}
     function frame2() {
      side--;
      element.style.left = side + "px";}
     function frameChecker(){
      element.id = pos;
      if (element.id > screen.height+20){element.remove();clearInterval(framee);clearInterval(framee2);clearInterval(frameCheckerr);}}}}
 </script>
  <title>GOT 404 ERROR</title>
</head>
<body onload="load()" id="body">
 <div style="width:100%; height:100%; position: relative;">
  <div class="center"><span>ERROR 404</span></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it was petty tuff to fund out, thanks to @Pointy for saying about the functions being allways on after called with `setInterval()` and also the first timer (`rain()`) can be used with timer set was 500 for better performace

Answer (score 0):

Every time your `rain()` function runs because of its interval timer (every 100 milliseconds), it starts three new interval timers with even faster intervals. After a minute or so, therefore, you'll have hundreds of interval timers running. That's what is making everything slow down.

You might consider `setTimeout()` for those nested functions. The `setTimeout` function calls it's callback only once after a single delay.

Comment: it makes the dots only move once (one pixel), is something i am missing?

Comment: @qwertytroll3 well I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but adding a "dot" every hundred milliseconds and then running three timers for each one is definitely going to bog the system down after a little while. I mean, think about it; after a minute there'll be 1800 timers running. That's just not sustainable.

Comment: yeah thats why i now added it to `frameChecker()` `if (element.id > screen.height+500){element.remove();clearInterval(framee);clearInterval(framee2);clearInterval(frameCheckerr);}}}}` and also added these `clearInterval` pointing to the timers who before just had `element.remove`